# “Uncaught reference error: initialize is not defined”

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I still have a problem with google maps initialization.
Also I can not see all the markers inserted.
I state that I do not know javascript, and I find it hard to understand where I'm wrong.
I looked at several posts, with my own question, but I did not succeed, to find the solution to my problem.

### this is my file googlemap.js

```
var markers = [
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Main Office - Malta', 35.895079, 14.49011], 
['<b style="color:red;"></br> Desk Office - Principaute de Monaco', 43.75042,7.438238],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Belgium', 50.50389, 4.46994],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Cyprus', 35.038174, 33.40443],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Hong-Kong', 22.354694, 114.131719],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Jersey', 40.727865, -74.078228],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office -  The Netherlands', 52.106505,5.515137],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Russia & CIS', 55.719648, 37.567421],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - United Kingdom', 52.509535,-0.791016],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - China', 34.412677, 103.954634],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office -  Guernsey', 40.725812,-73.954167],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Ireland', 40.737158, -73.886638],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office -  Luxembourg', 49.614561,6.132495],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office -  Mauritius', -20.286556, 57.504439],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office -  New-York', 40.729379, -74.003781],
['<b style="color:red;"></b></br> Desk Office - Singapore', 1.283094,103.8439]

     ];

function initializeMaps() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.895079, 14.49011);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    navigationControl: false,
navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.NORMAL},
streetViewControl: false,
//
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
},
  mapTypeControl: true,
 navigationControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions: {

 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT, style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, "blackMap"]

},


};    


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

//Bl map style


 var styleBl =
[


{
"featureType": "water",
"stylers": [
  { "saturation": -21 },
  { "hue": "#00e5ff" },
  { "lightness": 21 }
]


 },{
"featureType": "landscape",
"stylers": [
  { "hue": "#1f78c4" }
]


 },{
"featureType": "road",
"elementType": "labels.text",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "on" },
  { "color": "#354a82" }
]

 },{
 },{
"featureType": "poi.business"  }
]

 var styledMapOptions = {name: "Bl"}


 var blMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styleBwl, styledMapOptions);


 map.mapTypes.set("blackMap", blMapType);

map.setMapTypeId("blackMap");
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

var marker, i;
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
     var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
     bounds.extend(pos);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: pos,
     map: map
         });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
     return function() {
     infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
     })(marker, i));
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

any kind of help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: When you say not all markers are visible, do you mean they don't all get plotted as markers on the map, or just that they don't all fit in the visible part of the map you're zoomed into?

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are adding an event listener to a function that does not exist (`initialize`). Your function is called `initializeMaps` so change `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` to be `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMaps);`

Comment: putvande, thank you for your answer. Could you help me also for markers? are not all visible.